# Concurrent Processing of csv for multiple users

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, throttling, concurrent-programming

I have a scenario in which I have to process CSV files from a folder for users and store them into database after processing. We have 5 type of feeds per user.
Any user can send any feed in that folder, any time for processing, need to follow below rules:

- same type of feed for same client can't be processed at same means time must always be blocked from being processed concurrently.
- do not allow concurrent processing across more than "x" clients
- do not allow concurrent processing of more than "y" files for the same client

What is the good way to achieve this ?

Comment: so... a file for example has the name FEED1_CLIENT1?

Comment: Yep FEED_CLIENT_TIMESTAMP.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first restriction can be implemented with a map of [AtomicBoolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).  This probably doesn't need to be a ConcurrentHashMap, since you won't be changing the map's keys after initialization.  Don't forget to reset the feed's value to false when you're done.

```
checkAndProcessFeed(Feed feed, Map<String, AtomicBoolean> map) {
    while(!map.get(feed.type).compareAndSet(false, true)) // assuming the AtomicBooleans were initialized to false
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
    process(feed); // at this point map.get(feed.type).get() == true
    map.get(feed.type).set(false); // reset the AtomicBoolean to false
}
```

The other two restrictions can be implemented with [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), used to maintain a count of clients and per-client files; decrement when processing is complete, and increment with compare-and-set to start a new client/file.

```
final int maxClient = 5;
AtomicInteger clientCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Client> queue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>(); // hold waiting clients
while(true) {
    int temp = clientCount.intValue();
    if(!queue.isEmpty() && clientCount.compareAndSet(temp, temp + 1) { // thread-safe increment 
        process(clients.poll()); // don't forget to decrement the clientCount when the processing finishes
    } else Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Zim, looks promising to me. But one thing we have to process for multiple clients concurrently if files came in. Can you please also guide on how that logic should look like. is this throttling or thread pooling?

Comment: You'd use something like a ThreadPoolExecutor for this; `process(clients.poll())` in the above code would become `threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Processor(clients.poll())` where `Processor` implements `Runnable` and its `run` method implements the client processing logic.

Comment: One more twist, we don't want to process same kind of feed concurrent in any case to avoid any database locking.